# Why after connecting to VPN I can't browse some websites

Tags: vpn, browser

In my country some websites like twitter,youtube,facebook etc are blocked by government and we have to use VPN so we can access them, but somehow after I connect to VPN (openvpn and PPTP both have this problem) I can ping these websites and can resolve them with nslookup , but when it comes to browsers like chrome and firefox I can't browse some of them.
It's really interesting , I can browse youtube perfectly , but twitter won't load complete ([here](https://pasteboard.co/I6pSmOD.png)) , facebook doesn't load at all (there are some other websites that won't load at all like facebook)
I tried removing the cache of browsers and even with new and fresh installing without any caching this problem appears 
I change the DNS with `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/head` file

PS: I can all websites with their Domain Names

Comment: Look up how to reduce MSS and MTU. With OpenVPN the keyword is `mssfix`.

Comment: I would sniff local traffic (mostly DNS and tcp/80+443) and see where's the issue. Maybe MTR tool will be helpful here `mtr {facebook ip here}`.

Comment: thanks to you guys , the problem was MTU packets size

Answer (score 0):

I've searched many topics for this problem and I finally resolve the problem , the problem was the size of MTU packets of my Wlan card I reduce it to 1200 ( previous size was 1500 ) with `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 mtu 1200`
command ( wlp2s0 is my wireless card) and the problem was solved